# Passport authentication not work for one specific route with express router

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, express-session

I'm trying to access 'testpage' route. But the req.isAuthenticated() returns false only for this route. (This route was there before I started to add authentication).
I'm able to go to login page and authenticate with google. Then I can access 'signup' or 'user_profile' route without problems.

After login if I try:

> localhost:8080/testpage

the server sends me to "/". But if I try:

> localhost:8080/testpage#

with hash sign in the end, the page is rendered.

```
// routes/users.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function (passport) {
  router.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.render('login', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
  });

  router.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));

  router.get('/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
      successRedirect: '/',
      failureRedirect: '/'
    }));

  router.get('/user_profile', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    res.render('user_profile');
  });

  router.get('/signup', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    res.render('signup');
  });

  router.get('/testpage', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    res.render('testpage');
  });

  return router;

};

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();

  res.redirect('/');
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

---

*** update ***

Here my app.js

```
var express       = require('express');
var path          = require('path');
var favicon       = require('serve-favicon');
var logger        = require('morgan');
var cookieParser  = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
var passport      = require('passport');
var flash         = require('connect-flash');
var session       = require('express-session');
var db            = require('./mongoose');

var app = express();

require('./config/passport')(passport);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret123', 
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());


var users = require('./routes/users')(passport);

app.use('/', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});


module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 3):

It could be due to the express-session middleware that is needed for passport. you can fix it by using middleware in following order.

```
var session = require('express-session')
var app = express()
app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
app.use(session({
   secret: 'yoursecret',
   resave: true,
   saveUninitialized: true,
   cookie: { secure: true },
   // you can store your sessions in mongo or in mysql or redis where ever     you want.
   store: new MongoStore({
      url: "mongourl",
      collection: 'sessions' // collection in mongo where sessions are to be saved
   })
}))
// Init passport 
app.use(passport.initialize());
// persistent login sessions 
app.use(passport.session());
```

See https://github.com/expressjs/session for more details.

Also I think so you have not config google strategy.
try some thing like following

```
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuthStrategy;

// Use the GoogleStrategy within Passport.
//   Strategies in passport require a `verify` function, which accept
//   credentials (in this case, a token, tokenSecret, and Google profile), and
//   invoke a callback with a user object.

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    consumerKey: GOOGLE_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumerSecret: GOOGLE_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/google/callback"
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
      User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return done(err, user);
  });
}));
```

Comment: I updated my question, the app.js is almost equal as your answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer you can see if it can help. if not then check passport.serialize and passport.deserialize functions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after one entire day I just realized that when I was typing localhost:8000/testpage in the url bar it was been changed to www.localhost:8000/testpage. And the auth dos not work with www*. Another thing is that google chrome tries to predict what url you will type and this could cause this type of error, and it is annoying at debugging. So I unchecked this options at chrome's settings, preventing prediction.

[image: unchecked google chrome's settings]